# In python, how do I create an upper-diagonal table without the diagonal?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my current code

```
import numpy as np
with open("wine.txt","r") as f:
    stuff=f.readlines()
z=[]
for hello in stuff:
    firstbook=hello.strip().split(",")
    x=[float(xy) for xy in firstbook]
    z.append(x)
u=np.array(z)
gridList = []
for item in range(14):
    row=[]
    for nlist in u:
        row.append(nlist[item])
    gridList.append(row)
column=13
r=[]
while column >= 0:
    recess=column-1
    while recess >= 0:
        r.append(np.corrcoef(gridList[recess],gridList[column]))
        recess=recess - 1
    column=column-1
print len(r),r[90][1][0],r[0][1][0]
print "column -->      1    2    3     4    5    6    7     8    9   10    11   12    13   14"
print 87*"-"
chucky=0
while chucky<1:
    print "column=", chucky, "|",
    princess = 90
    while princess >=77:
        print round((r[princess][1][0]),2),
        princess-=1
    chucky+=1
```

I'm debating on whether or not to do this the hard way, write a bunch of while loops, but I know there's a much simpler way to write this code.  I need to create an upper diagonal table without the diagonal, there's a total of 91 values I need to put in. As you can see, I calculated the pearson r-value between the columns of data and assigned it to r, where I can retrieve the correlation value of each 2x2 matrix by simply printing 
`r[i][1][0] for i in range(90)` for each matrix. I know writing the code for a upper diagonal table w/o the diagonal shouldn't be a problem, but what I'm having trouble with is something to the like of this, the first row of the table should contain the following values r[90][1][0] r[89][1][0] r[87][1][0] r[84][1][0] r[80][1][0] etc. So how do I use a loop to write in those values,starting from 90, who decrease from 90 at a pace of increasing positive integers?

Let me know if you want the data to play with the code

Comment: Index arrays with x[i,j,k] instead of [i][j]...  It's easier to read.  Also identify shapes and dtype of arrays.

Comment: Look at the np.tri... family of functions; and np.diag...

Comment: Thank you, I will try these methods out

Answer (score 0):

numpy.triu gets the upper triangle and the 1 is what takes out the diagonal

```
import numpy as np
np.triu([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], 1)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html